# JQuery order of function execution not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function

```js
function disableButton(element, callback) {
  $(element + " .loading-spinner").css('display', 'inline-block');
  $(element).attr("disabled", true);
  alert('1');
  callback();
}

function enableButton(element, callback) {
  $(element + " .loading-spinner").css('display', 'none');
  $(element).attr("disabled", false);
  alert('3');
  callback();
}

function executeAjax(data, callback) {
  alert('2');
  callback();
}

$( ".custom-button" ).click(function(e) {
    disableButton('.custom-button', function() {
      executeAjax('testdata', function() {
        enableButton('.custom-button', function() {});
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="custom-button"><span class="loading-spinner" style="display:none;">Loading </span>BUTTON</button>
```

I have some problems with the order in which functions are executed. I tried to use promises and callbacks to fix it, but it all doesn't help.

I have these three functions: disableButton(), enableButton() & executeAjax()

The problem is: the alerts all popup in the right order: 1, 2 and 3. But... the enable and disable state is not working. It works if I use a timeout, but otherwise the css and disable state are not executed in the right order. How can I fix this?

Comment: `the css and disable state are not executed in the right order.` - what order are they executed in? note: don't use alert for debugging, use console.log instead, alerts are modal and can confuse the issue

Comment: Are they working properly when you don't actually do an AJAX call? or is the AJAX call causing the problem?

Comment: You can only disable form elements and they cannot have any child elements. Something is not right in here!

Comment: @undefined - you can disable a `fieldset` - they have children

Comment: Are you not sharing your AJAX code with us, or you're testing it as-is, with dummy code in `executeAjax`?

Comment: @JaromandaX [You are right!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset#Attributes). I didn't know that.

Comment: @undefined - I only learned that today, but it's not 100%, I've seen controls that remain enabled!! HTML is great until it isn't

Comment: I don't do an AJAX call yet. This is all the code I currently have.

Comment: @Jordy no working fiddle of this code?

Comment: @vibs2006, nope, the code above is all I have!

Comment: Changes to `disabled` and `display` are only visibly updated by the browser when the browser is *not* busy running javascript. In your case the browser is always busy running javascript, so YES the in-memory properties change, but NO these changes are not effectuated on the page and thus not visible to the user, until all javascript code has finished running.

Comment: So, how can I fix this?